# Accessing position direction inside Strategy object in Backtesting.py

Tags: python, pandas, trading, back-testing

I am currently working on a strategy that uses moving average crossovers to detect a top or bottom in a correlated security to the market which I have found to be leading.  I am running into a problem where I need to determine whether or not I am in a long or short position so that I can avoid closing a long trade, for example, only to buy back into the long trade.
My code is similar to this:

```
class example(Strategy):

    def init(self):
            super().init()
            self.ma = self.I(SMA, self.data.Close, self.n1)
            
        def next(self):
            price = self.data.Close
    
            # Long
            if self.data.Condition == -1.0:
                self.position.close()
                self.buy(size = .9999)
               
            # Short
            elif self.data.Condition == 1.0 and price < self.ma:
                self.position.close()
                self.sell(size = .9999)
                
            elif 1.0 in self.data.Condition[-self.lookback:]:
                if price < self.ma:
                    self.position.close()
                    self.sell(size = .9999)
```

If anyone could help me with a basic example of how to use the is_short or is_long position instance variables, I would be extremely appreciative. I am looking to do something similar to this:

```
class example(Strategy):

    def init(self):
            super().init()
            self.ma = self.I(SMA, self.data.Close, self.n1)
            
        def next(self):
            price = self.data.Close
    
            # Long
            if self.position is_short:
                if self.data.Condition == -1.0:
                    self.position.close()
                    self.buy(size = .9999)

            elif self.position is_long:
                if self.data.Condition == -1.0:
                    pass

 # Left out short side for simplicity, but hopefully you get the idea.
```

I am extremely excited about my strategy, and would appreciate any help in checking current position direction. I believe it would improve the strategies performance and give me a better idea of how the strategy I am envisioning would perform under real conditions.
Thank you very much in advance!

I tried accessing the instance variables as described in the documentation, but was not able to utilize the is_long or is_short variables in my strategy. I also searched reddit and stackoverflow, but was unable to find anything related to my issue of double orders.

Comment: What's wrong with using [`Strategy.position.size`](https://kernc.github.io/backtesting.py/doc/backtesting/backtesting.html#backtesting.backtesting.Position.size) or `self.position.is_long/is_short`? You're simply missing an attribute-accessor dot (`.`) in your second example.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish my task by creating logical trackers for short position, long position, and open position (to start off or in case of stop loss). These are updated based on trades (i.e. a short trade would mean short_pos is True, and would allow for a long position to exit the trade)

A brief example:

```
class VIX(Strategy):

lookback = 7
short_position = False
long_position = False
overall_position = False

def init(self):
    super().init()
    
def next(self):
    price = self.data.Close

    # Long
    if self.data.Position == -1.0 and self.short_position == True:
        self.buy(size = .9999)
        self.long_position = True
        self.short_position = False
        self.overall_position = True
```